# Stop users with contributor rights from deleting documents 

Tags: wss-3.0

We have a wss 3.0 site that has a document library based on a custom list definition.

We would like to block users that have contributor rights from deleting documents, what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to create a custom Permission Level and exclude Delete Permission from it. Here an article I wrote about that scenario: [Document libraries: Specify which items users can edit/delete – explained – Part 1](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2008/06/document-libraries-specify-which-items-users-can-edit-delete-explained-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we ended up implementing a custom security check in the ItemDeleting event.